# How to pass large buffers to OpenCL devices?

Tags: c#, opencl, cloo

I'm writing a program on C# using OpenCL (Cloo.dll) and i need to pass the large buffer to OpenCL ComputeDevice. When I pass this buffer to OpenCL ComputeDevice - program crashes without any exception or error.

Code:

```
    ComputeBuffer<Byte> dataBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<Byte>(this._context,
        ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.CopyHostPointer, data.LongLength, ptrData);
    ComputeBuffer<Byte> keysBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<Byte>(this._context,
        ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.CopyHostPointer, Keys);
    ComputeBuffer<Byte> resultBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<Byte>(this._context,
        ComputeMemoryFlags.WriteOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.CopyHostPointer, result.LongLength, ptrResult);


    this._kernel = this._program.CreateKernel("AES_ECB_Encrypt");

    this._kernel.SetMemoryArgument(0, dataBuffer);
    this._kernel.SetMemoryArgument(1, keysBuffer);
    this._kernel.SetValueArgument<int>(2, 10);
    this._kernel.SetValueArgument<long>(3, data.LongLength);
    this._kernel.SetMemoryArgument(4, resultBuffer);

    ComputeDevice bestDevice = this._devices[0];

    this._queue = new ComputeCommandQueue(this._context, bestDevice, ComputeCommandQueueFlags.None);
    this._queue.Execute(this._kernel, null, new long[] {data.LongLength}, null, null); // here is the crash.
```

OpenCL Kernel:

```
kernel void AES_ECB_Encrypt(__global uchar16* InputData,__global uchar16* Keys,int GRounds,ulong GLength,__global uchar16* Result)
{
    int Index=get_global_id(0);

    int Rounds=GRounds;
    ulong Length=GLength;

    if (Index<Length){
        uchar16 State=TurnData(InputData[Index]);

        State=AddRoundKey(State,Keys[0]);

        for (int round=1;round<Rounds;round++){
            State=SubBytes(State);
            State=ShiftRows(State);
            State=MixColumns(State);
            State=AddRoundKey(State,Keys[round]);}


        State=SubBytes(State);
        State=ShiftRows(State);
        State=AddRoundKey(State,Keys[Rounds]);

        Result[Index]=TurnData(State);}
}
```

I read about ComputeDevice.MaxParameterSize - maximum size of parameter that can be passed to device. To my mind, the problem is here, because small buffers (size < 1KB) can be passed well.
MaxParameterSizes in my devices are 1024 and 4096 bytes, but these values are very small. I need to pass buffers with size over 100 MB.

How can I pass a large buffer to device? Can I pass only a pointer to this buffer?

**My OpenCL Devices:**

AMD Radeon HD8750M 2048MB,

Intel Core I3 4000M + 6GB RAM

## **Edited**:

Because of kernel works with `uchar16` data, i have to set GlobalSize as `buffer.size / 16`.

I only changed one line of code(buffer size divides by 16):

```
this._queue.Execute(this._kernel, null, new long[] {data.LongLength/16}, null, null);
```

Everything works fine. Thanks everyone!!!)

Comment: More than 100 MB? I think you should try EnqueueMapBuffer() + EnqueueUnmapMemObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MaxParameterSize` query specifies that maximum size needed to store the argument *values*, not the size of the buffers that those arguments might point to.

To find out how large a single buffer can be, you need to check the `MaxMemoryAllocationSize` query. The OpenCL 1.2 spec mandates that this will be *at least* 128MB, but it will probably be more, depending on the device.

Comment: You are right about MaxParametrSize. I have corrected my mistake. New code in my edited answer.